# Compressing AMD graphics include directory "asic_reg" saves up to 230MB Linux Kernel storage size. Can cloned downloads be partly unpacked by git?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, git, storage

Cloning a current kernel (e.g. [5.17-rc1](https://kernel.org) ) to a source directory requires around 1.4GB and a total of 2GB (debug kernels up to 4GB) free storage for compiling a default kernel configuration.
While AMD's gpu include files are a huge part of that source download (mostly asic_reg directory) these are only required with utilizing an AMD gpu.
Compressing this `drivers/gpu/drm/amd/include/asic_reg` directory to an `asic_reg.bz2` file (about 9MB) and removing the asic_reg folder, reduces kernel sources by almost 230MB to then around 1.0GB size (`.git` directory pack files cleared) on client side.

Compiling from sources was flawless, having only that bzip2 file available and no AMD gpu devices configured.
If there are any unusual drawbacks to this approach, that aren't obvious by now (beside decompressing this file within a few tens of seconds at most, if needed for AMD gpu driver support), hints are welcome.
**Storage savings** would be an advantage **of almost 230MB**, with automated decompressing and compressing during the common kernel compiling procedure, if needed.
**(Would it be possible to modify the make build system for that?)**

The question for modifying the make build system arises secondary to only partly decompressing a downloaded git archive.
**Is there a possibility for partly unpacking a kernel archive, cloned by `git`, depending on a configuration file for that kernel, given previously to unpacking?**
(included: Can `git ?clone?` stop before unpacking? )

So far that had no interest, because there are no hints or questions about that idea/improvement within **Unix & Linux** database.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but it seems relatively harmless as long as whoever downloads it understands that they'll have to decompress the amd gpu files if they need them and knows how to do so.   I don't really get the point of your question, though.  if this is for your own use and it works for you, then you don't need permission.  if it's for random third-parties, then it's not a good idea.  either way, it seems off-topic for this site, entirely subjective and likely to get opinions rather than answers.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the kernel source repository should contain a compressed archive instead of individual source files? This would break the source code management as you could no longer see the changes in the source code using Git. BTW when you clone the repository, the data is transferred in compressed form, so you probably won't see the expected download savings.

Comment: edited question with support from comments for being more precisely, thanks

Comment: I still don't understand what you want/need. You want to shrink your unpacked kernel sources? With today's storage capacities I'm a little baffled. A 4TB HDD may contain 2000 unpacked kernel sources. Lastly, bzip2 is too slow nowadays. I'd highly recommend using ZSTD instead which sports a comparable compression ratio but unpacks up to 50 times faster.

Comment: being an attempt to source code management, replying with git clone/pull statistics been useful (AFAIK not avail., maybe with smth. like gource? or gitstats?) for understanding, how many would (~25yrs from 2.x-5.1x, debug, production, realtime, virtualization versions for diff. architectures), how many times, save around 1/6th of disk usage for kernel source storage (each new version, 'make clean') within that approach (downloading a ~9MB bzip2 (pbzip2 (de)compr. 3-5s, mainstrm?) separately - not preferred). Until better results for stats: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Development

Comment: It might be seen like expanding on ["Fast Kernel Headers"](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/YdIfz+LMewetSaEB@gmail.com) and also might get obsolete with reduced impact of AMD graphics includes within source code. The advantage of source being visible (means directly accessible) only if configuration enabled that parts (otherwise stored compressed, on client side), would be a more general view to this topic (comparable to compressed kernel modules, if configured for lzma, e.g `*.ko.xz` )? Thx, for all contribution